# Estimating mean and variance of a component of dyadic decomposition of sub-Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a sub-Gaussian random variable, i.e., it satisfies 
$$ \textbf{P}(|X|\ge t) \le C\exp(-ct^2)$$
for all $t >0$ and some $C,c>0$.
Consider a dyadic decomposition, i.e.,
$$ X = X_0 + \sum_{m=1}^\infty X_m$$
where $X_m = X\textbf{I}(2^{m-1}<|X|\le 2^m)$ and $X_0 = X\textbf{I}(|X|\le 1)$.

What I want to show is that 
$$ \textbf{E} X_m , \textbf{Var} X_m = \mathcal{O}(C'\exp(-c'2^{2m}))$$ for some $C',c'>0$.
FYI, this appear in the proof of Prop 2.1.9. in [Tao's random matrix theory](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf).

To estimate mean of $X_m$, it suffices to consider $|X_m|$.
Since $|X_m|\le 2^m$ and , I got
\begin{align}
\textbf{E} |X_m| &= \int_{0}^\infty \textbf{P}(|X_m| > x) dx = \int_0^{2^m} \textbf{P}(|X_m| > x) dx \\
&= 2^{m-1}\textbf{P}(2^{m-1}<|X|\le 2^m) + \int_{2^{m-1}}^{2^m} \textbf{P}(2^m \ge |X|>x)dx \\
&\le 2^m \textbf{P}(2^{m-1}<|X|\le 2^m) \le 2^m \textbf{P}(|X|> 2^{m-1}) \\
&\le 2^mC\exp(-c2^{2(m-1)}) = C'\exp(-c'2^{2m})
\end{align}
where $C'=2^mC$ and $c'=c/4$.
Similarly,
\begin{align}
\textbf{Var}X_m &\le \textbf{E}X_m^2 = \int_{0}^\infty \textbf{P}(|X_m|^2 > x) dx 
= \int_{0}^{2^{2m}} \textbf{P}(|X_m| > \sqrt{x}) dx  \\
&\le 2^{2m}\textbf{P}(2^{m-1}<|X|\le 2^m) \le 2^{2m}C\exp(-c2^{2(m-1)}) \\
&= C'\exp(-c'2^{2m})
\end{align}
where $C' = 2^{2m}C$, and $c'=c/4$.

But I am not sure whether $C'$ is meant to be dependent with $m$.
If my derivation is correct, I believe $C'$ should be denoted by $C'_m$ to show its dependency on $m$.

Any thought, comments, answers will be very appreciated. Thanks!